# How to calculate a tax deduced from it own base in R?

Tags: r, iteration

My issue may be a math issue rather than an R issue, but if someone has the solution it would help me :

I need to calculate a tax with a tricky base : the idea is that the tax itself is deduced from the base, which involve an iterative calculation.

Example : If the revenu is 1000 and the tax rate 10%, we should to 1000 - 100 = 900, then 1000 - 90 = 910, then 1000 - 91 = 909, etc until revenu - tax = tax base. Excel does it automatically if I refer to the cell itself, however I need to do it in R.

For now, I came out with this result, but I was hoping that I could do it without coding a specific function?

```
iterativeCalculation <- function(base, rate){
  result = base
  while(result != base - result * rate){
    result = base - result * rate
  }
  result
}
```

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: `x * 1.1 = 1000`, so `1000 / 1.1 = x = 909.0909` You don't need iteration, you just need to divide by 1 + tax rate.  `revenue / (1 + tax rate) = tax base`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was indeed simply to divide revenu by (1+tax rate).

You don't need iteration, you just need to divide by 1 + tax rate.

```
1000 / 1.1 = x = 909.0909
1000 / 1.1 = x = 909.0909
revenue / (1 + tax rate) = tax base
```